# Converting Full Month Name String into MMM format

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting month number as integer and want to convert it to `MMM` format 
here is what i have tried but its giving me full month name

```
public String getMonth(int month) {
         return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
            }
```

it gives me `April` in return  but i want `Apr`

Comment: The correct method is *literally* right below the one you're using in the Javadoc for DateFormatSymbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do this is

```
new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths()[month-1];
```

as described in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `subString` method or you can change Date Formatter.

```
public String getMonth(int month) {
         return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1].subString(0,2);
            }
```

Using `Date Formatter`:

```
public String getMonth(int month) {
             return new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths()[month-1].subString(0,2);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` as below...

```
public String getMonth(int month) {

    String monthName="";

    try {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return monthName;
}
```